# Is there a way to place a variable in the child pseudo-class of a Java Css Selector Loop

Tags: java, loops, selenium

I have a list of glyphicons that download a file when clicked. I'm looking to run through all glyphicons in a loop.

Each glyphicon has pretty much the same Css Selector, only difference being the tr:nth-child() number which ranges from 1 - 10. I have it marked in the code below bracketed in asterixes where this number usually is.

Is there a way to insert the i variable in this psuedo class so that I can download each glyphicon file once clicked in the loop.

If there is a more efficient way to do this, please let me know.

```
public void Download(){ 
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#content > div.container > div:nth-child(3) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(****Insert i Variable Here****) > td:nth-child(7) > a")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public void Download(){ 
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#content > div.container > div:nth-child(3) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-child(7) > a")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!